# How to validate whether an integer is a validate date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

User need to input a string as an integer and also as a date in the format of `yyyymmdd` like `20150127`.

It needs to be pure integer and an absolute validate date. For example, either `20150011` or `20150230` won't be valid.

The way I am currently doing is just simply split the string into `year`, `month`, `day`, then try to validate them myself. For example, `month` must be within `[1,12]`, etc.

But ideally, I would like to try to parse it as a correct date, otherwise, I can't handle the case where a month is lack a day, like there is no 31 for Feb or April, etc.

How can I do this validation perfectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var y = str.substr(0,4),
        m = str.substr(4,2) - 1,
        d = str.substr(6,2);
    var D = new Date(y,m,d);
    return (D.getFullYear() == y && D.getMonth() == m && D.getDate() == d) ? D : false;
}

console.log(parseDate('20150131')); // returns Sat Jan 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
console.log(parseDate('20150231')); // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "moment.js" javascript library for the validation.

```
var m = moment("2011-10-10T10:20:90");
m.isValid(); // false
```